# How to put line break between th and td?

Tags: html, css

I have table and I would like to put my td's under th tags. Here is my HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>Your Email</th>
       <td>
          <input type="text" name="userEmail" value="" id="userEmail" required="">
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Job Category</th>
       //I need break line here
       <td>
          <label><input type="radio" name="rd1" value="Programmer" id="rd1">Programmer</label><br>
          <label><input type="radio" name="rd2" value="Web Developer" id="rd2">Web Developer</label><br>
       </td>
    <tr>
 </table>
```

My output gives me text in `<th>` tags and then text in `<td>` tags next to it. I would like to have td content below th. I tried to use `<br>` tags but looks like that does not work outside of td tags. If anyone know the best and way to fix this please let me know.

Comment: Are you able to restructure your HTML?

Comment: What do you mean by "My output gives me text in <th> tags and then text in <td> tags next to it."?

Comment: Output is on the same line, I want to put content from td under th.

Comment: close tr after </th> and then open tr again, puts them in different table rows.

Comment: Are you unable to change the HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a table and nothing can be put outside the table cells. If you want to have the forms element under the headers, just create one row with headers and one row with forms elements:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>Your Email</th>
       <th>Job Category</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <input type="text" name="userEmail" value="" id="userEmail" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
          <label><input type="radio" name="rd1" value="Programmer" id="rd1">Programmer</label><br>
          <label><input type="radio" name="rd2" value="Web Developer" id="rd2">Web Developer</label><br>
       </td>
    <tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: So I have question, If I have multiple elements that have to be structured the same way (each th in separate row and each td in separate row) is that correct and the best way to do that?

Comment: You can have multiples elements in a table cell (td or th) and you can have line breaks between them (<br/>) but inside the cell and not between them.

Answer (score 3):

Put your table header in its own row:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Your Email</th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="userEmail" value="" id="userEmail" required="">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Job Category</th>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    //I need break line here
    <td colspan="2">
      <label><input type="radio" name="rd1" value="Programmer" id="rd1">Programmer</label><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="rd2" value="Web Developer" id="rd2">Web Developer</label><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When using th together with td in same row, you should also set scope="row" on the th so screen readers know to what the header belong

Comment: @LGSon - Thanks, I do appreciate the comments.  It helps us all in the end

Answer (score 1):

Place them in different rows using

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Your Email</th>
        <td>
           <input type="text" name="userEmail" value="" id="userEmail" required="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Job Category</th>
    </tr>//End row
       //I need break line here
    <tr> //start new row
        <td>
            <label><input type="radio" name="rd1" value="Programmer" id="rd1">Programmer</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="rd2" value="Web Developer" id="rd2">Web Developer</label><br>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So I have question, If I have multiple elements that have to be structured the same way (each th in separate row and each td in separate row) is that correct and the best way to do that?

Comment: @user3023588 Use Orden's answer/solution

Comment: @LGSon IT says each th and td in separate row, Orden's answer has all th in one row all td in the next row. https://jsfiddle.net/8b3uvw3b/1/ This shows the difference

Comment: Yes, and Orden have that, though he added 2 of each, which likely the OP wants based on his existing structure. Also you have a faulty structure, having 2 cells in some rows and 1 cell in some. For this to work properly colspan should be set.

Comment: One more thing, when using th together with td in same row, you should also set scope="row" on the th so screen readers know to what the header belong